# IIS URL Rewrite except specific site

Tags: asp.net, redirect, iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I have 3 sites (with different domains) which are hosted on one server, but all of them have same source and `web.config`. Sites 1 and 2 will be stopped and they should redirect to Site 4, but Site 3 will work as now...
I added a RewriteMap where described all pages redirects and a rule which is using that map:

```
 <rewrite>
      <rewriteMaps>
        <rewriteMap name="My_RewriteMap" defaultValue="localhost/site4/Welcome.aspx">
          <add key="/" value="localhost/site4/Welcome.aspx" />
          <add key="/default.aspx" value="localhost/site4/Welcome.aspx" />
          <add key="localhost/site2" value="localhost/site4/SpecificPage.aspx" />
          <add key="/page3.aspx" value="localhost/site4/MyPage.aspx" />
          <add key="new-page.aspx" value="localhost/site4/TheNewPage.aspx" />
...
</rewriteMap>
          </rewriteMaps>
          <rules>
                <rule name="Redirect rule1 for My_RewriteMap" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" negate="false" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{My_RewriteMap:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule>
          </rules>
        </rewrite>
```

This code works for described pages in Map and for default value (if a specific page doesn't exist in the Map).
But this redirects Site 1, Site 2 and Site 3. I don't want to redirect to for Site3.
Is it possible with Rewrite URL feature?
I tried to edit `match` value with

```
<match url="localhost/Site3" negate="true" />
```

or

```
<match url="(localhost/Site3).*" negate="true" />
```

But both didn't work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Completed with next changes in conditions:

```
<conditions trackAllCaptures="true">
  <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="localhost/Site3" negate="true" />
  <add input="{My_RewriteMap:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
</conditions>
```

With the first condition, I say to ignore all requests where Host (in `{HTTP_HOST}` variable) contains the site's domain: `localhost/Site3`.
Then, the second condition works for the Map.